# What is the PDF sum of N random variables

Tags: probability, self-study, density-function

I have N random variables: $X_1,...,X_N$ which are all independent. The PDF (probability density function) of each random variable $f_{X_i}=e^{-a/(x^{2/b})}x^{-(4+b)/b}$. What is the PDF $f_S(x)$ where $S=X_1+...+X_N$.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question requires the self-study tag. Expect hints but not complete answers.

Comment: I tried the moment generating function but I was stacked. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Presumably you mean "stuck" rather than "stacked". Your density doesn't integrate to 1 but the density of $x^{2/b}$ looks proportional to an inverse gamma (or $1/x$ looks proportional to a generalized gamma. How does this problem arise? Are you sure you need a closed form for the pdf here?

Comment: ...you're aware of the convolution method, right?

Comment: It seems that there is no closed form for the PDF. Really I tried many methods (even the convolution) but always I didn't find solution. Did you think that I have to use an approximation?